# SQLite3 unrecognized token warning

Tags: php, sqlite

When I try to execute my SQLite3 statement in PHP, I get the following:

```
Warning: SQLite3::exec(): unrecognized token: "38360f81b43f97437a01ce7294ce41f9" in /path/to/register.php on line of error
```

So I go to look at the execution:

```
$user = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

$encrypted_pass = md5($pass);

class DB extends SQLite3{
    function __construct(){
            $this->open('/path/to/db/userpass.db')
    }
}

$db = new DB();

$stmt = 'INSERT INTO userpass VALUES(' . $user . ', ' . $encrypted_pass . ');';

if($db->exec($stmt)){ //line of error
    header('Location: http://192.168.1.147/registered.html');
} else {
    die(1);
}
```

As you can see, `$pass` is hashed and stored as `$encrypted_pass`, which is used to be inserted into my table.

Comment: you need to quote the strings

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong

```
$stmt = 'INSERT INTO userpass VALUES(' . $user . ', ' . $encrypted_pass . ');';
```

and this is ok!

```
$stmt = "INSERT INTO userpass VALUES(' . $user . ', ' . $encrypted_pass . ');";
```

or

```
$stmt = 'INSERT INTO userpass VALUES(" . $user . ", " . $encrypted_pass . ");';
```

Answer (score -1):

Missing semicolon on this line

```
$this->open('/path/to/db/userpass.db');
```

And also remove semicolon from here

```
$stmt = 'INSERT INTO userpass VALUES(' . '$user' . ', ' . '$encrypted_pass' . ')';
```